# Is it correct usecase for IORef?

Tags: scala, io, functional-programming, scalaz, ioref

The goal is to ask person to enter an integer, and verify that it is indeed an integer. If it is not - then ask again. 
The first attempt was to use **ioMonad.whileM,** becasue it actually returns value inside IO, and write something like that (then we can "safely" cast String to Int):

```
 val input: IO[Option[String]] = ioMonad.whileM(readLn.map(_ exists notDigit),
 askAndReadNumber)(scalaz.std.AllInstances.optionInstance)
```

But that approach did not work out, because in the condition, I am not only validating the value, but also reading it from console once again.

So, since I need to read the input, and then pass it somehow to the condition, I was thinking, that **IORef** might be exactly the right tool (I never used it before, so consider this as my humble attempt to learn functional programming). 
I ended up with that:

```
def requireNumber: IO[Int] = {    
    val numref: IO[IORef[String]] = newIORef("a")
    ioMonad.whileM_(condition(numref), askAndReadNumberToIORef(numref))
    numref.flatMap(_.read).map(_.toInt)
  }

  def condition(num: IO[IORef[String]]): IO[Boolean] = for {
    ref ← num
    enteredNumber ← ref.read
  } yield enteredNumber exists notDigit

  def askAndReadNumberToIORef(num: IO[IORef[String]]): IO[Unit] = for {
    ref ← num
    input ← askAndReadNumber
    _ ← ref.write(input)
  } yield ()

  private def notDigit: (Char) ⇒ Boolean =
    !Character.isDigit(_)

  def askAndReadNumber: IO[String] =
    for {
    _ ← putStrLn("Enter a number please")
    maxN ← readLn
  } yield maxN
```

And what happening is - actually the whole loop is completely ignored, and the program goes directly to the line with initial ref:

```
num.flatMap(_.read).map(_.toInt)
```

So, do I misuse **Ref** concept here? Why is it not working?

Thanks

**Update:**
Actually I solved the initial problem by writing this method:

```
def whileMpropagating[M[_], A](f: ⇒ M[A])(p: A ⇒ Boolean)(implicit M: Monad[M]): M[A] =
    M.bind(f)(value ⇒ if (!p(value)) f else whileMpropagating(f)(p))
```

and then `whileMpropagating(askAndReadNumber)(_ forall notDigit)(ioMonad) map (_.toInt)`

But still I am interested in utilizing the IORef here.

**Update2:** My shame, `iterateWhile` in Monad does exaclty this : )

Answer (score 1):

`IORef` is overkill for your case. This is the solution in few lines of code:

```
import scala.util.Try
import scalaz.effect.IO
import scalaz.syntax.monad._

private def isInteger(str: String) = Try(Integer.parseInt(str)).isSuccess

val requireNumber: IO[Int] = IO.readLn.iterateUntil(isInteger).map(Integer.parseInt)
```

`IORef` represents a mutable reference (which functional programming is trying to avoid), and it should be used very sparingly. It is always a good idea to solve your problem by trying to write pure functions first.